# Using propensity scores to calculate average treatment effects

Tags: anova, confidence-interval, causality, propensity-scores

I have obtained class probabilities for 0 or 1 classes ("control", "treatment"). can I also  assume that these are also the propensity scores. If so, how do i use these probabilities or propensity scores) to calculate average treatment effects

Comment: You should check out one of the many introductions to propensity score analysis available. One I like a lot is [Austin (2011)](http://doi.org/10.1080/00273171.2011.568786). You shouldn't do a propensity score analysis unless you know why you're doing it, though. There are other, often more effective, ways of estimating average treatment effects.

Comment: Thanks Noah. I will read the article by Austin.

Comment: I have used the matching package by Sekhon  and my issue is getting the matched data set. The documentation does not explain how to do it for propensity score matching it only explains for genMatch which I am not using.

Comment: That's a programming question, please ask on StackOverflow and I can try to answer it for you.